# jQuery checkbox styling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox, styling

I have a piece of jQuery code, which I use to check if a checkbox is not checked. If not, it throws an event. Here it is:

```
$('#Button').click(function() {
        if(!$('input[@name=\"image_id\"]:checked').val()){
            //Do Something
            return false;
            }
});
```

It works great, but i decided to style the default checkbox with [jQuery Checkbox](http://widowmaker.kiev.ua/checkbox/) plugin.

Now heres the problem, This is what the output is after styling:

```
<input type="radio" name="answer_id" value="37" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;">`
<span class="jquery-safari-checkbox jquery-safari-checkbox-checked"><span class="mark"><img src="empty.png"></span></span>
```

thus leaving me with no way to see if the input is checked. Any ideas on what I can do (if anything) or shall i just revert to the old checkboxes?

Comment: @name has not been in jQuery since version 1.2! Are you using a really old version of jQuery?

Comment: What's the problem?  Does the plugin not leave the original checkbox intact?  Most styling plugins will just hide the original checkbox, but still maintain its state so you don't have to play games with determining its value or submitting it with a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special.  The original checkbox is still there and maintains its state.  When you click the fancy checkbox, the plugin updates the hidden checkbox to match the current state.

You can update your code a little, too, if you use the latest jQuery.  Your code is quite antiquated:

```
$('#Button').click(function () {
    if (!$('input[name=image_id]').prop('checked')) {
        //Do something
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k2d6E/

Comment: yes, my code was quite old and outdated by the looks of things. thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

Kinda messy in my opinion to do this this way, but:

```
if($(".jquery-safari-checkbox").hasClass("jquery-safari-checkbox-checked")){
   //Do something
   return false;
}
```